# What was the unknown catalyst which allowed Proto-Adamantium to exist?

Tags: captain-america, marvel, adamantium, vibranium

We keep looking for an unknown agent but we must look at the fact:

Dr. Myron MacLain used an **experimental Steel alloy** and **Vibranium**; He did numerous test using different setting and combination (amount of components, different pressures and temperatures) all of them were obviously recorded. During one of those tests he fall asleep while waiting for the metal to "heat up".

So what was responsible for the Proto-Adamantium formation since we know all the main component of the shield?

[image: page from the comic]

Comment: It was, um, _unknown_.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Donald Rumsfeld? Is that you?

Comment: @Darren That is a known unknown. You know?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- **Answer:**

The fact is that Marvel set what allowed the Proto-Adamantium to exist a total **unknown**. It is a mystery and will probably stay that way. We can only speculate on what was this *unknown factor*.

Comment: “the true secret behind the Proto-Adamantium was never published and probably never will” — you do know that comics aren’t documentaries, right?

Comment: Generally speaking we don't like speculative answers on this site; your answer is reasonable and seems valid but it would benefit from some more direct references from the source material.

Comment: I am with Michael on this. You need some basis for your assertion, whether it's evidence from the comics, a comment from one of the people who worked on the series, or an appeal to metallurgical principles. That said, it's a good start at an answer.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I know, English isn't my native language and published was the most suitable words at that time.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield My reasoning directly from what as been said in the comics. The fact is the answer was never given to us by marvel. At which point does a theory is accepted as answer? I'll do my best to put more details.

Comment: @Xainfinen: no no, “published” is a fine word. My query was because you’re talking about “the true secret” behind proto-adamantium — this “true” secret only exists if the writers made it up. If they didn’t make one up, it doesn’t exist. Of course, it’s valid to try to make sense of the story as written to figure out what the secret could be, but this story pretty clearly looks like it’s trying to convey an *unknown* origin, not an origin for us to puzzle out from clues.

Comment: @Xainfinen: regarding quote markup, don’t use that for things that aren’t quotes. It’s not there to provide different visual effects; it’s there to indicate things that are quotes.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Okay thanks for the feedback Paul. So what are you suggesting?

Comment: @Xainfinen: I’m pointing out that answers on this site are meant to be based on evidence from the fictional works they’re discussing. Obviously, there’s a fine line between explaining a story and speculating about the parts it leaves blank, but I think you’re on the side of speculation here.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Alright, thank you. I understand and have separated the fact from my theory.

Comment: @Xainfinen: awesome! Now just delete the whole theory part, and you’ve got a suitable Stack Exchange answer.